# Potential conflicts when calling and rendering API data in a Laravel project with both web pages and APIs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I'm working on a Laravel (version 10) project that combines both web pages and APIs. In this project, I'm calling an API to fetch a list of users and then rendering this data in the form of a table on a web page. However, I'm concerned about potential conflicts or issues that might arise because the web page and the API are part of the same project.

I have created a simple API within my Laravel project to fetch user data. When I call this API in isolation, it successfully returns the data of the users as expected.

I expected that when I integrate this API into my project and call it from a web page, it would still retrieve and display the user data without any issues.

However, when I attempt to call the API from within my project's web page, I encounter timeout errors.

API code:

```
public function index() {
 $emplyopees = Employee::all();
 return response()->json($emplyopees);
 }
```

For calling API:

```
 public function index() {
 $response = Http::get('127.0.0.1:8000/api/users');
 return $response->successful();
 }
```

For the sake of simplicity I'm not rendering the data on web page. They are on different controllers

Comment: Timeouts could occur when the time to fetch the users from the API takes longer than [the PHP default 30 seconds](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). You're probably trying to perform too many API calls. I can't tell because there's no code in your question.

Comment: API code:
public function index()
    {
        $emplyopees = Employee::all();
        return response()->json($emplyopees);
    }

For calling API:
public function index()
{
        $response = Http::get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users');
        return $response->successful();
}

For the sake of simplicity i'm not rendering the data on web page.
They are on different controllers.

Comment: does the api call timeout or the php script? Your api requests, in isolation and within the webpage, might have different timeout configurations.